# Bootstrap Footer covering Body content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, footer, sticky-footer

In the below example code, the footer is covering the body content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
    }
    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light self-navbar text-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/project/new_version/"><img src="" alt="Website" title="Website" width="30" height="30" loading="lazy" />&nbsp;Website</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav self-first-ul">
      Slogan
    </ul>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto self-second-ul">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/919595951111"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> 9595951111</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="mailto:email@site.com"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> email@site.com</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="tel:9595950000"><i class="fas fa-mobile-alt"></i> 9595950000</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </span>
  </nav>

  <div class="container p-3 bg-white rounded">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade d-none d-md-block d-lg-none" data-ride="carousel">

      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <div class="row">
          
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">C6</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">00</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">C8</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">00</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">C5</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">00</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div class="row">
    <label for="Number">Search your transaction here <i class="far fa-hand-point-down far-blink"></i></label>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" id="number" name="srch_num">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-addon2" value="Search" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p><a href="http://localhost/project/new_version/how2search" target="_blank">How to search specific transaction?</a></p>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Company Name</h3>
          <p>Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph. Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph. Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph. Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph. Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph.
            Some text to be shown. This will be a paragraph.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
          <h3>Links</h3>
          <ul class="list-unstyled footer-links">
            <li><a href="#home-section">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#category-section">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact-section">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="tnc.php">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a href="refund_policy.php">Refund Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h3>Dial Sales & Support</h3>
          <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a class="dial_link" href="tel:'.$website_phone.'" title="Dial  '.$website_phone.'"> '.$website_phone.'</a></p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a class="dial_link" href="tel:'.$website_mobile.'" title="Dial  '.$website_mobile.'">'.$website_mobile.'</a></p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a class="dial_link" href="https://wa.me/91'.$website_wamobile.'" title="Whatsapp  '.$website_wamobile.'">'.$website_wamobile.'</a></p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong></strong><a href="mailto:'.$website_email.'"> '.$website_email.'</a></p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><strong></strong> Monday to Saturday</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong></strong> 10am to 6pm</p>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="row pt-5 text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="border-top pt-5">
            <p>
              Website Slogan

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

What actually I want is, the footer should always be in the bottom. Like if there are long body content (scrollable) then footer should be in last. But if the content is very few, finishes in one/two line the footer should be in bottom last. No space after that.

Comment: add sticky or fixed to footer with bottom:0

Comment: No, @SandrinJoy that didn't solve my question.

Comment: then , what it displayed?

Comment: I already have position as absolute in the footer. Check https://jsfiddle.net/4azxgfb3/, for position as sticky.

Comment: I have posted as answer.Please review it

Answer (score 0):

**Using Flexbox**

```js
$("#add").on("click", function() {
  $("<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>").appendTo(".content");
});
```

```css
html, body {
  /* IE 10-11 didn't like using min-height */
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  padding: 20px;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevent Chrome, Opera, and Safari from letting these items shrink to smaller than their content's default minimum size. */
  padding: 20px;
  background:#fe5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sticky Footer with Flexbox</h1>
  <p><button id="add">Add Content</button></p>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
```

Comment: The footer shouldn't be fixed, it should be only shown in last. (with no white space after that, if the content is small)

Comment: your question is not proper. Footer covering body? footer is inside body

Comment: Joy, Let's go step by step then. what I want is the footer to be always in last, but not fixed.

Comment: So , like stackoverflow footer? If it is , i have updated the answer

Comment: Ys, but not complete. Like here https://jsfiddle.net/4azxgfb3/1/, the footer is somewhere in the middle, but it should be in the bottom. The whitespace below footer should be above in this case.

Comment: So , if content  is less that that of screen size , u need it bottom 0 and if its greater than the screen size , u need it in the end?

Comment: Agreed with your last comment fully. FYI - I am using bootstrap 4.5

Comment: then as i said earlier , sticky will help you for that

Comment: I tried that https://jsfiddle.net/4azxgfb3/ earlier, but not working for me.

Comment: I have updated the answe using flexbox, we can do this in many ways https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/